# Trying to make a code with VBA for excel

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to make a code for a spreadsheet I'm working on, I do not have prior experience and found an example online. The first part of the code works fine, but when I try to bring in the second "if not" my code does not run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range"Adv1Monday"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        With Range("Adv1Monday")
            .Copy Destination:=Sheets("Adventure 1").Range("C2")
            If Not Intersect(Range("Adv2Monday"), Target) Is Nothing Then
                With Range("Adv2Monday")
                   .Copy Destination:=Sheets("Adventure 2").Range("C2")
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: To know what the expected behavior is, you will need to describe what you want to happen.

Comment: Well first it will only run the second IF statement if the the first IF statement is true. Is that what you want? Also you many want to rethink your structures. For one, I would strongly discourage putting one Range With block inside another Range With block. I don't like cascading With blocks at all but definitely wouldn't with the same data type.

Comment: use `Intersect(Range("Adv1Monday"), Target)` instead of `Intersect(Range"Adv1Monday"), Target)`

Answer (score 2):

**If....end If** and **With...End with**.  They were not closed properly:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Range"Adv1Monday"), Target) Is Nothing Then
   With Range("Adv1Monday")
    .Copy Destination:=Sheets("Adventure 1").Range("C2")
   End With
  End If
  If Not Intersect(Range("Adv2Monday"), Target) Is Nothing Then
   With Range("Adv2Monday")
     .Copy Destination:=Sheets("Adventure 2").Range("C2")
   End With
  End If
End Sub
```